# Update PowerShell version in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017

I ran the following in the Visual Studio 2017 Package Manager Console -

```
PM> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

 Major  Minor  Build  Revision
 -----  -----  -----  -------- 
 2      0      -1     -1
```

When I run the same command from a PowerShell window I get -

```
PS C:\>  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

This is causing me a problem because I want to run something in the package manager that requires PowerShell 3 or above.

Comment: thought of updating powershell tool ?

Comment: It is up to date - PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017 version 3.0.427

Comment: It is up to date NOW - PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017 version 3.0.585. Thanks @collin-Chaffin

Comment: Accept the answer given by Colin

Comment: @RanadipDutta what I updated was PowerShell Tools extensions, but  PowerShell is still showing up as V2.

Comment: Means the PS Engine is not getting updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I updated Visual Studio 2017 to 15.3.3 (there was no update available when I posted the question), and I also installed a few Windows updates.

Here the two windows updates -

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3134760/windows-management-framework-5-0-rtm-on-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-serv

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the latest version of the tools.  The latest version per this page:

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2017-18561
```

Lists the version/update as:

```
3.0.585 updated 7/6/2017, 9:04:51 AM.
```

Comment: For some reason VS 2017 was telling me that it was up to date. I just installed the newer version, but the original problem remains.

Comment: So you updated and reran the $psversion and still got v2?

Comment: See https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/issues/497
based on that post it looks like there was an issue with the version range for which you had installed which required a full UNINSTALL of the tools not just an upgrade, so personally I would UNINSTALL the PStool package and do a full reboot, then reinstall that latest version

Comment: Yes, reran $PSVersionTable.PSVersion and got  v2.

Comment: Did you see my last comment it is clear from that developer that very often you need to fully uninstall and reinstall a different version and not simply upgrade I find multiple similar issues so please fully uninstall and remove that extension and reboot then reinstall the latest version and try it again please.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Full uninstall of powertools, reboot, reinstall. Same problem -  "PowerShell version 2.0 is not supported. Please upgrade PowerShell to 3.0 or greater and restart Visual Studio."